# Batch command to move files to a new directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to write a batch job that when executed will grab all the files in the `C:\Test\Log` folder and move them to a new directory in the `C:\Test`. This new directory will have a name called "Backup-" and CURRENT DATE.

So once completed, the log folder should be empty with all the files now located in the new folder.

I know I would have to use the `MOVE` command, but have no idea how to dynamically create a new folder, and use the date to name it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Something like this might help:

```
SET Today=%Date:~10,4%%Date:~4,2%%Date:~7,2%
mkdir C:\Test\Backup-%Today%
move C:\Test\Log\*.* C:\Test\Backup-%Today%\
SET Today=
```

The important part is the first line. It takes the output of the internal `DATE` value and parses it into an environmental variable named `Today`, in the format `CCYYMMDD`, as in '20110407`.

The `%Date:~10,4%` says to extract a *substring of the `Date` environmental variable 'Thu 04/07/2011' (built in - type `echo %Date%` at a command prompt)  starting at position 10 for 4 characters (`2011`). It then concatenates another substring of `Date:` starting at position 4 for 2 chars (`04`), and then concats two additional characters starting at position 7 (`07`).

*The substring value starting points are 0-based.

You may need to adjust these values depending on the date format in your locale, but this should give you a starting point.

Comment: +1, No need for locale adjustment, [Date](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/date.mspx?mfr=true) is always *mm-dd-yy*

Comment: @Sertac: Thanks. Wasn't sure about that, so wanted to warn just in case.

Comment: @Sertac, that's nonsense. `%DATE%` returns the date formatted in the short date format, which is ISO-8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) here and could be anything from a wide range of different formats.

Comment: @Joey you are right  `%DATE%` returns the current date using the short date format that is fully (endlessly) customizable. So one user may configure its system to return Fri040811 while another may choose 08/04/2011... it's a complete nightmare for a BAT programmer.

Comment: @PA: Use `wmic os get localdatetime` instead, then.

Comment: Thats nice, thanks. BTW, I have previously used `WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year /Format:table` which is convenient as it is directly parsed with a `for`

Comment: puting the pieces together, applied to Ken's answer, the one liner would be `FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (SET /A TODAY=%%F*10000+%%D*100+%%A)`

Comment: @PA: Nice, didn't know that one. `Win32_UtcTime` could come in handy as well there.

Comment: thanks. I was able to get it to work. I added time too, in case it ran more than once a day.

Answer (score 0):

this will also work, if you like

```
 xcopy  C:\Test\Log "c:\Test\Backup-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%" /s /i
 del C:\Test\Log
```