# move files to one directory

Tags: batch-file, dos

DOS bat
I want to find files with a certain extension, for example
where /R c:\ *.ppx
and move them all to a specified directory, for example   c:\PPS
Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at this [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588264/batch-command-to-move-files-to-a-new-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output of `WHERE` to a file

```
WHERE /R C:\ *.ppx > ppxlist.txt
```

And then use a `FOR` loop to move them

```
FOR /f %i in (ppxlist.txt) do move %i c:\pps\
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar question that suggests a few methods:

[How can I recursively copy files of a specific pattern into a single flat folder on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246559/how-can-i-recursively-copy-files-of-a-specific-pattern-into-a-single-flat-folder)